# Dynamically Changing TargetName DoubleAnimation c# xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, doubleanimation

im searching for a solution to change the TargetNameproperty in my code behind.
in total i need 9 different images / animations to happen. in the example below there are just 2.

here is the XAML

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MyAnimationBoard1" x:Key="MyAnimationBoard">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Anim1"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:0.5"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-30" KeyTime="0:0:0.10"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:0.20"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-30" KeyTime="0:0:0.30"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:0.40"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Anim2"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:4"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:4.5"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-30" KeyTime="0:0:4.10"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:4.20"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-30" KeyTime="0:0:4.30"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:4.40"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
```

Here you find the way i call the animations to begin in code behind

```
if (timesTicked == 59)
            {
                string voedsel = "Food1";
                Animate.AnimateFood(voedsel);
                //Would be nice to call the correct tagretname first.
                MyAnimationBoard1.Begin();
            }
            else if (timesTicked == 52)
            {
                string voedsel = "Food3";
                Animate.AnimateFood(voedsel);
                Debug.WriteLine("Tweede animatie");
                
            }
            else if (timesTicked == 46)
            {
                string voedsel = "Food8";
                Animate.AnimateFood(voedsel);
                Debug.WriteLine("Derde animatie");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Storyboard.SetTargetName(Timeline, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.settargetname?view=winrt-19041) to change the value of `TargetName` property of a `DoubleAnimation` dynamically. You need to add a `Name` for every `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`.

For example:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MyAnimationBoard1" x:Key="MyAnimationBoard">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="DoubleAnimation1"
                Storyboard.TargetName="Anim1"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)">
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:0.5"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-30" KeyTime="0:0:0.10"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:0.20"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-30" KeyTime="0:0:0.30"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:0.40"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="DoubleAnimation2"
                Storyboard.TargetName="Anim2"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)">
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:4"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:4.5"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-30" KeyTime="0:0:4.10"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:4.20"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-30" KeyTime="0:0:4.30"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:4.40"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
//
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyAnimationBoard1.Stop();
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(DoubleAnimation1, "Anim2");
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(DoubleAnimation2, "Anim3");
    MyAnimationBoard1.Begin();
}
```